# Finding specific item and change value in model - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, model, codable

I am trying to change value or update value in model but for some unknown reason it's not updating value.
I have accurately found the row by matching id's but after that value is not updating.
I want to update `bgColor` in `Item` model.

Deceleration: `var AppDetailData : AppointmentDetail?`

My Code:

```
for var i in AppDetailData?.sectionList ?? [] {
                for j in i.items ?? [] {
                    
                    if let row = i.items?.firstIndex(where: {$0.unitId == id}) {
                        i.items?[row].bgColor = "yellow"
                    }
                }
            }
```

JSON Model:

```
struct AppointmentDetail : Codable {
    
    let projectId : Int?
    let projectName : String?
    let projectNo : String?
    let projectType : String?
    let sectionList : [SectionList]?
    
}

struct SectionList : Codable {
    
    let title : String?
    var sectionId: Int?
    var items : [Item]?
}

struct Item : Codable {
    var bgColor : String?
    var unitId : Int?
    var latitude : Double?
    var longitude : Double?
    }
```

Comment: Why is everything declared optional? Is this your json or from some external rest api?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - My Json, yes I will set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you change your array properties to be `var` declared and not optional and the `unitId` (all *Id properties really) to non optional you can use the following

```
for (index, appointment) in appointments.enumerated() {
    for (index1, section) in appointment.sectionList.enumerated() {
        if let index2 = section.items.firstIndex(where: {$0.unitId == id}) {
            appointments[index].sectionList[index1].items[index2].bgColor = "yellow"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your model is define as Struct, so to modify you must call AppDetailsData..... to change. For example:
change your sectionList variable from let to var, and change your code with this

```
        guard let list = AppDetailData?.sectionList else {
            return
        }
        if let index = list.firstIndex(where: {$0.items?.first?.unitId == 1}) {
            AppDetailData?.sectionList?[index].items?[0].bgColor = "yeallow"
        }
```

Comment: I have tried your code but specific value still not updated.

Comment: is AppDetailData?.sectionList?[index].items?[0] is the item you want to change ???

Comment: Thank you so much support, I have made little changes and now its working.